# com.google.firebase.database VS com.firebase.client

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was just thinking about what is the different between those 2 libraries

As what is the diffrenet betweent coding this:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("https://....firebaseio.com/");
```

And this:

```
Firebase RootRef = new Firebase("https://....firebaseio.com/");
```

---

Also I was trying to make it more simpler by using just the `com.google.firebase.database` library by coding:

```
FirebaseDatabase RootRef =
        new FirebaseDatabase("https://.....firebaseio.com/");
```

And it gives me error:

```
Error:(18, 46) error: constructor FirebaseDatabase in class FirebaseDatabase cannot be applied to given types;
required: FirebaseApp,zzbpk,zzbpb
found: String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Aslo on pointing to FirebaseDatabase it displays:

```
'FirebaseDatabase(com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp, com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpk, com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpb)' has private access in 'com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase'
```

Thanks in advance wish it be simple to readers
Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're two different major versions of the Firebase SDK:

- `com.firebase` is the 1.x or 2.x SDK as it was shipped prior to I/O 2016.
- `com.google.firebase` is the SDK as it's been shipped since I/O 2016. Since this version is partially bundled with Google Play Services, is matches that library's version: 10.x right now, but any 9.0 or higher includes Firebase support.

Given that we're rapidly approaching I/O 2017, you should not start any new project on the 2.x SDK anymore.

To prevent getting syntax errors:

- refer to the [official Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android)
- use the [migration guide](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android) if you have code that was written for the 2.x SDK
- avoid using outdated tutorials